# rust-analyzer Failed to discover workspace when using VS Code with more than 1 project in the workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

Using the latest Rust Analyzer, I have a workspace that contains more than 1 project, but it keeps printing errors as shown in the attached image.
[image]

test1: Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

web1 Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "main"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
```

lanch.json in both :

```
{
    // The following are sample configurations for common case scenarios of debugging
    // Rust in Visual Studio Code
    //
    // For syntax, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    //
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch an application",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [ "arg1", "arg2" ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        },        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing as suggested in the pop-up?

Comment: its vccode configuration to make workspace and hold 2 projects not rust configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `Cargo.toml` for your parent directory (as a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html)). Create one and make `web1` and `test1` members of it. Or, better, if `test1` contains tests for `web1`, make it [integration tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#integration-tests) instead.

Comment: how can i make test1 and web1 memebrs in cargo.toml ? its not related to VCCODE no? 
its rust configuration file , any example ?

Comment: @user63898 rust-analyzer looks for it. For examples, look at the documentation I linked.